# How to use run_function in a tellraw command?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to run a tellraw command with a clickEvent using the `run_function` action. My command looks like this, but it didn't work:

```
/tellraw @a [{"text": "test","clickEvent":{"action":"run_function","value":"tutorial:test"}}]
```

The file path to my .mcfunction files is `data/tutorial/functions/test.mcfunction`.

So my question here is, did I use the wrong path to my .mcfunction?
And can I still use the run_function in 1.20.1?

Comment: I don't think you can run a function directly like that, I think you can use the `run_command` action and use the function command. Something like this: `{"action":"run_command","value":"function tutorial:test"}`, I haven't tried it myself.

Comment: Thank you that worked :)

Comment: Added an answer so you can mark your question as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax:

```
/tellraw @a [{"text": "test","clickEvent":{"action":"run_command","value":"function tutorial:test"}}]
```